# Интегральные типы

Tags: c++, типы, условия

Почему конструкция switch case работает только с интегральными типами, и что вообще такое интегральные типы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Термин "integral" ("интегральный") является синонимом термина "integer" ("целочисленный"). Так что интегральные типы - это просто все целочисленные типы.

Конструкция `switch/case` работает только с целочисленными типами потому, что, во-первых, ей нужен тип с четко и однозначно определенным отношением строгого равенства, что, например, исключает использование плавающих типов. В этом отношении `switch/case` аналогичен нетиповым шаблонным параметрам, которые тоже поддерживают только типы с четко определенным отношением равенства.

Во-вторых, эта конструкция изначально задумывалась не просто как "синтаксический сахар", а с задней мыслью о том, что во многих случаях структура переходов в `switch/case` будет поддаваться очевидным оптимизациям: табличной реализации или реализации через прямое вычисление целевого адреса. Для "сложных" типов, вроде строк, возникновение возможности такой оптимизации выглядит существенно менее вероятным, чем для целочисленных типов.

Разумеется, в современном С++ не составило бы, наверное, большого труда расширить диапазон поддерживаемых в `switch/case` типов. Но, насколько я знаю, таких планов пока нет.

Comment: Можно добавить, что всё же можно прикрутить СИ-шные строки и массивы в case с помощью constexpr хэш-функции, а в C++20 сделают возможным создавать контейнеры при компиляции, тогда можно будет прикрутить и их.

Comment: @Beaver Feller, и как при этом решать проблему коллизий когда две разных строки дают один и тот же дайджест?

Comment: @freim для заранее известного неизменяемого множества ключей можно сделать хэш-функцию без коллизий (идеальная хэш-функция)

Comment: @Beaver Feller, то есть это можно использовать только для заданного  ограниченного набора строк? И для каждого такого набора подбирать свою хеш функцию? Я бы сказал, что ценность такого метода немного ограничена. Примерно так нулем.

Comment: @freim функция пишется один раз, набор задаёт программист (для case-ов), хэши высчитываются на этапе компиляции (что как бы и требует константного размера набора константных ключей, а для такого набора можно сделать хэши без коллизий).

Comment: @Beaver Feller, это будет работать только если строка в switch гарантированно принадлежит к множеству строк, для которых подсчитаны дайджесты. В противном случае случае возможны коллизии со всеми вытекающими. В общем, метод крайне ограниченной применимости.

Comment: @freim внезапно, но то, о чём вы говорите можно сделать с чем угодно. Только смысл? Зачем мне в case пихать строки вне моего множества? К тому же я не говорил, что это полезно, а просто сказал, что возможно. https://ideone.com/va1s0m

Comment: @Beaver Feller, смысл в том, что значение `switch` не совпадающее ни с одним `case` есть вполне штатная ситуация, которую оператор **обязан** обработать корректно. С вашим методом он будет выбирать неправильный `case`, то есть работать неправильно. Такое решение в принципе недопустимо.

Answer (score 3):

Сначала  представим как работает эта конструкция. Не точно, но логика такая:

```
int  val[] = {3, 4, 7},  Cswitch_case =4;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    if (!(val[i] ^ Cswitch_case)) // так проверяет switch
        cout << i;
```

Т.е.  выполняется битовая операция, результат которого дает команду по какой метке выполнять программу. (правда, еще проверку, что оба нули, я не дописал).

А для неинтегральных типов, обычно это невозможно. Например:
    }

```
string s1("first"), s2 = s1;
//        if(!(s1 ^ s2))  эта битовая операция невозможна
//            cout << "....";
```

Поэтому было введено ограничение...

Comment: это предположение? почему в Java например можно делать так со строками. Я думал switch/case разворачиваются в хещ-таблицу

Comment: @pavel,  я подробности не знаю,  проверка на равенство по любому существует, и тут она выполняется  именно битовой операцией. Всегда можно написать любую свою крнструкцию, и если в Java можно, я не вижу в этом ничего особенного...